# After installing macbuntu theme, VMware menus disappear

Tags: 10.10, themes, vmware, macbuntu

I installed the [macbuntu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/macbuntu/) theme, for Ubuntu 10.10, and the menus from the VMware application disappeared. The other applications are correctly showing the menus. Any idea how to get back the VMware menus (other them completely uninstalling macbuntu)?

Comment: Do you have `appmenu-gtk` package installed?

Comment: @Salem yes, I do. Maybe I should re-install it?

Comment: well, you can try it. But probably it's a problem of VMWare (i found something similar, regarding globalmenu http://goo.gl/L3BVK)

Comment: @Salem In my case it don't even appear in the global menu bar.

Comment: @Salem and reinstalling `appmenu-gtk` didn't make any change.

Comment: I don't have 10.10. The appmenu-gtk tip was because in 11.10, if you uninstall that package, menu returns to windows. Just one more thing: try installing `appmenu-qt`. Maybe VMWare uses Qt as toolkit... Good luck

Comment: @Salem Thanks for the hints. Unfortunately, `appmenu-qt` didn't solve it also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstall appmenu-gtk, and appmenu-qt and make a reboot, the mouse and keyboard were no more reponsive. I re-installed Ubuntu, and [still had some trouble with macbuntu after formating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84081/how-to-complete-remove-macbuntu-even-by-formatting), but now the system is ok (without macbuntu).

Looks like macbuntu is not much stable.