# How to complete remove macbuntu (even by formatting)?

Tags: 10.10, themes, macbuntu

I just format my root partition (and keep my Home partition), and reinstalled Ubuntu 10.10. But the theme of macbuntu is still there.

If I try to run it's "uninstall.sh" even with "--force" I get "The script is not able to determine what version is currently installed" (the version is 10.10).

By the way, I also deleted ".macbuntu" from my Home directory, but I'm still not able to uninstall it.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a GTK+ theme, then it would have left some files in `~/.themes`, possibly also in `~/.icons` and others.

To be certain, you can manually open the uninstall script, look for all folders that are marked for removal, and manually clean these up your self.

Comment: It solved partially, the colors, icons and fonts are back. Now I'm looking the script and trying to see how to get the gnome-panel back to the normal.

Comment: @TomBrito: If you are on GNOME 2.xx, you will need to delete the gnome-panel gconf directory.

Comment: Ok, I manually run some more commands of the script (of the end of it) and looks like everything is ok now =)

Comment: @that would be your system's shortcuts. It's in system settings somewhere. If you are using compiz, you need to enable gnome compatibility in ccsm.

Answer (score 1):

macbuntu cannot determine the currently installed version probably *because* you deleted the `~/.macbuntu` folder.

To still uninstall macbuntu, you need to tweak the uninstall script so it will omit the checks in the files:

1. Back up your home directory (please really do that!):

   ```
   sudo cp -r ~ /home/backup
   ```
2. Open the uninstall script `uninstall.sh` and comment the following lines (put a `#` in front of them):

   ```
   chk_version
   chk_user
   ```
3. Run the uninstall script `uninstall.sh`. Cross fingers ;)